# How I disable Windows authentication in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a local SQL Server 2005 running and I need to disable Windows authentication, I want that the only way to be connected to the server is by using an specific SQL user (SQL authentication).

Comment: This is off-topic, should be on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable Windows authentication. If you don't want a Windows account to have access to SQL Server, don't create a login for it in SQL Server.